# Laravel 5 Eloquent where with multiple or in Clauses

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am new in Laravel and I try to get results from table with multiple where and or clauses.

```
Cases::select()
  ->where('accepting_id', '=', '1')
  ->where('status', '=', 'active')
  ->orWhere("status", '=', 'closed')
  ->orWhere("status", '=', 'canceled')
  ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
  ->get();
```

I'm getting incorrect data by using mulitple `orWhere`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$user = Cases::select(`cols`)
              ->where('accepting_id', '=', '1')
              ->whereIn('status',  ['active', 'closed', 'canceled'])
              ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
              ->get();

dd($user);
```

Try this

Answer (score 3):

You would need to add the `status` where clauses to a where closure:

```
Cases::select()
    ->where('accepting_id', '=', '1')
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('status', '=', 'active')
            ->orWhere("status", '=', 'closed')
            ->orWhere("status", '=', 'canceled');
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: `return` statement not need

Answer (score 2):

Instead of use multy `orWhere()` use `whereIn()`

```
Cases::select(`cols`)
    ->where('accepting_id', '=', '1')
    ->whereIn('status',  ['active', 'closed', 'canceled'])
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Also if you want to group some queryies

```
Cases::select(`cols`)
    ->where('accepting_id', '=', '1')
    ->where(function ($q) {
        $q->where(`condition1`)
            ->orWhere(`condition1`);
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Deleted my answer as yours is better

Comment: @thisiskelvin your answer also helpful.

Comment: It can help other situation